# How to save odd number objects on one node and even number objects on another node in Ignite

Tags: ignite

I recently started using Ignite and seems very useful. I have 2 nodes(n1, n2) and I have like 100,000 objects (say Person object)with keys as integers starting from 1 till 100,000 that should be saved on both nodes. I want 1,3,5,7,9....... person objects to be saved on node n1 and 2,4,6,8,........ person objects to be saved on node n2. Is it possible to achieve this using partitioned cache mode? If yes could you please let me know how?  Thanks, Rishi

Answer (score 0):

This is also discussed on Apache Ignite user forum: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/How-to-save-odd-number-objects-on-one-node-and-even-number-objects-on-another-node-td9567.html